# Is there a way to log what application or device is using a USB port?

Tags: usb, shell, powershell, process, logging

I have a DAQ connected through USB, and every now and then it drops signal and the application using it crashes. I have a feeling that some other process or service is interrupting the USB. Is there a shell script I can use to log information on what application is using the USB port, or what device is connected to the USB port? I realize there are programs to see what process is using a device at a certain point in time, but I need to also see what device is actually connected to that port, and be able to log it.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the drop in signal could be do to the Motherboard's power requirement. Try connecting the DAQ into a powered USB Hub. If it's plugged into the PC, ensure it's plugged into a dedicated powered USB port ([identified with lightning bolt](http://www.google.ca/imgres?imgurl=http://img.sg.dell.com/fileup/at.asp%253Ffn%253D200812198484982490.jpg&imgrefurl=http://empegbbs.com/ubbthreads.php/topics/364113/Charging_USB_hub&h=205&w=400&tbnid=ZDI5SQ2k0ayAcM:&docid=AS1glefuox8kSM&ei=fAZGVoGgIMKyeoucjqAN&tbm=isch&ved=0CBwQMygAMABqFQoTCIHO5oPgjckCFUKZHgodC44D1A))

Check to see if the OS detects the loss/disconnection, check log files.

Comment: The DAQ is externally powered. I've also set it not to go into power saving mode.